# How to watch a Vuex getter in Composition API (Vue 3)

Tags: javascript, vuex, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

The state of my application seems to load AFTER my components get loaded, so my thought was to watch for the state-getter. But how do I watch a Vuex getter in the composition API?

My state & getter:

```
state: () => ({
    companies: [],
  }),
  getters: {
    getAvailableCompanies(state) {
      return state.companies
    }
  },
  [...]
}
```

In my module, I import the store:

```
import { store } from '@/store/store.js'
```

And get the value of the getter in the setup() function of my component:

```
const companies = ref(store.getters["companies/getAvailableCompanies"])
console.log("companies", companies)
```

Now I am trying to watch for changes (also in setup()), once the state is populated:

```
watch(
  companies, (curr, old) => {
    console.log(curr, old)
  }
)
```

Unfortunately, `companies.value` never changes and stays `undefined`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `ref` in this case is not correct since AFAIK the value of `ref` variable is set at the moment you assign and only change when you re-assing its value. For example:

```
const companies = ref(store.getters["companies/getAvailableCompanies"]);
companies.value = [];
```

To re-calculate your companies array when the data is ready (changed) in the store, you need to use `computed` instead.

```
const companies = computed(() => store.getters["companies/getAvailableCompanies"]);
```

You can verify by using your watch or see the update in the view.

Comment: Will have a look at that later. Thanks so far